# What dictates whether a plugin will be available to a site in a multisite install?

Tags: multisite, buddypress

If I enable, for example, buddypress on a multisite install by going to `Network -> plugins -> network activate`, why does it not appear in `My Sites -> Name of Site-> Dashboard -> plugins` as activated?

I've observed that sometimes activating a plugin network wide will make it available to be enabled / disabled in a network site but not for all plugins. What causes this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Plugin that are already activated per network are hidden from the single site’s plugin list. Plugins with a header `Network: true` are always hidden, even when they are not activated.